# Update entities fields with data from other entity symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have two tables in database - orders and trucks. They have relation ManyToOne. When I receive order - truck field is null by default. Trucks table have preconfig data. So my task: for every order entity which I restore with findAll() method and send to twig (render as table) make checkbox, so I can appoint truck to every order.
Here is form which appoint truck to order:

```
    class TruckType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Trucks',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ));

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Orders',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'TruckType';
    }

}
```

And twig:

```
            {% for order in orders %}
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">{{ order.name }}</td>
            <td width="30%">{{ order.delivery }}</td>
            <td width="15%">{{ order.stock }}</td>
            <td width="15%">{{ form_widget(truckform) }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

But this render checkbox only for first entity in table. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the code for how you generate your `truckform` variable but I guess you just instantiate a form using your `TruckType` form type. The problem with this approach is that Symfony will not render a form or a form field more than once, so that your `{{ form_widget(truckform) }}` fragment is only rendered the first loop iteration. If you think about it, it makes sense, otherwise you will have a number of form fields *all with the same name and id* and when you submitted your form, there will be no way to differentiate them. You need to take a different approach, using embedded forms. Take a look at this Symfony doc page which will point you in the right direction: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)